# Allocating a temporary variable or compute the expression twice

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to write a code as efficient as possible and I encountered the following situation:

```
int foo(int a, int b, int c) 
{
    return (a + b) % c; 
}
```

All good! But what if I want to check if the result of the expression to be different of a constant lets say `myConst`. Lets say I can afford a temporary variable.

What method is the fastest of the following:

```
int foo(int a, int b, int c) 
{
    return (((a + b) % c) != myConst) ? (a + b) % c : myException; 
}
```

or

```
int foo(int a, int b, int c) 
{
    int tmp = (a + b) % c
    return (tmp != myConst) ? tmp : myException; 
}
```

I can't decide. Where is the 'line' where recalculation is more expensive than allocating and deallocating a temporary variable or the other way around.

Comment: What is `myException`? An `int`?

Comment: It's like this.  You will spend, liike, 1% of your time writing code and 90% time debugging and testing.  Imagine stepping through this code and needing to check values.  Which is easiest?

Comment: With MSVC 2015 it doesn't even generate any instructions for either function. It just optimizes them away completely.

Comment: @flatmouse, shouldn't and can't. It is an externally visible function with return value depending on input, it can't optimize it away.

Comment: Unless you've travelled here from the distant past, a local primitive variable  has no cost whatsoever. Division is the more expensive operation by far, and that in turn will often be dwarfed by the branch. (A beginner's intuition about performance is usually approximately 100% wrong.)

Comment: @SergeyA It can, and it has. I've posted the surprising result as an additional answer.

Comment: @molbdnilo, it doesn't even have to be a branch!

Comment: @molbdnilo:  When you say "a beginner's intuition" - I have managed to intuit where the performance hotspot was in my code twice so far.  That *is* twice in 35 years!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't worry about it, write concise code and leave micro-optimizations to the compiler.

In your example writing the same calculation twice is error prone - so do not do this. In your specific example, compiler is more than likely to avoid creating a temporary on the stack at all!

Your example can (does on my compiler) produce following assembly (i have replaced `myConst` with `constexpr` 42 and `myException` with 0):

```
foo(int, int, int):
        leal    (%rdi,%rsi), %eax       # this adds a and b, puts result to eax
        movl    %edx, %ecx      # loads c
        cltd
        idivl   %ecx  # performs division, puts result into edx
        movl    $0, %eax        #, prepares to return exception value
        cmpl    $42, %edx       #, compares result of division with magic const
        cmovne  %edx, %eax  # overwrites pessimized exception if all is cool
        ret
```

As you see, there is no temporary anywhere in sight!

Answer (score 6):

Use the later.

1. You're not computing the same value twice.
2. The code is more clear.
3. Creating local variables on the stack doesn't take any significant amount of time.

Answer (score 5):

Check the assembler code this generates for both versions. You most likely want the highest optimization settings for your compiler.

You may very well find out the compiler itself can figure out the intermediate value is used twice, but only inside the function, so safe to store in a register.

Answer (score 4):

To add to what has already been posted, ease of debugging is at least as important as code efficiency, (if there is any effect on code efficiency which, as others have posted, is unlikely with optimization on).

Go with the easiest to follow, test and debug.

Use a temp var.

If more developers used simpler, non-compound expressions and more temp vars, there would be far fewer 'Help - I cannot debug my code!' posts to SO.

Comment: I like the 'less posts on SO' as a valid reason to go with a better code!

Answer (score 0):

### Hard coded values

The following only applies to hard coded values (even if they aren't `const` or `constexpr`)

In the following example on MSVC 2015 they were optimized away completely and replaced only with `mov edx, result` (=1 in this example):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

int myConst{4};
int myException{2};

int foo1(int a,int b,int c)
{
    return (((a + b) % c) != myConst) ? (a + b) % c : myException;
}

int foo2(int a,int b,int c)
{
    int tmp = (a + b) % c;
    return (tmp != myConst) ? tmp : myException;
}

int main()
{
00007FF71F0E1000 48 83 EC 28          sub         rsp,28h  
    auto test1{foo1(5,2,3)};
    auto test2{foo2(5,2,3)};

    std::cout << test1 <<'\n';
00007FF71F0E1004 48 8B 0D 75 20 00 00 mov         rcx,qword ptr [__imp_std::cout (07FF71F0E3080h)]  
00007FF71F0E100B BA 01 00 00 00       mov         edx,1  
00007FF71F0E1010 FF 15 72 20 00 00    call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (07FF71F0E3088h)]  
00007FF71F0E1016 48 8B C8             mov         rcx,rax  
00007FF71F0E1019 E8 B2 00 00 00       call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (07FF71F0E10D0h)  
    std::cout << test2 <<'\n';
00007FF71F0E101E 48 8B 0D 5B 20 00 00 mov         rcx,qword ptr [__imp_std::cout (07FF71F0E3080h)]  
00007FF71F0E1025 BA 01 00 00 00       mov         edx,1  
00007FF71F0E102A FF 15 58 20 00 00    call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (07FF71F0E3088h)]  
00007FF71F0E1030 48 8B C8             mov         rcx,rax  
00007FF71F0E1033 E8 98 00 00 00       call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (07FF71F0E10D0h)  


    return 0;
00007FF71F0E1038 33 C0                xor         eax,eax  
}
00007FF71F0E103A 48 83 C4 28          add         rsp,28h  
00007FF71F0E103E C3                   ret
```

At this point other have pointed out that the optimization will not happen if the values were passed, or if we had separate files, but it seems even if the code is in separate compilation units the optimization is still done and we don't get any instructions for these functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>


#include "Header.h"

int main()
{
00007FF667BF1000 48 83 EC 28          sub         rsp,28h  
    int var1{5},var2{2},var3{3};
    auto test1{foo1(var1,var2,var3)};
    auto test2{foo2(var1,var2,var3)};

    std::cout << test1 <<'\n';
00007FF667BF1004 48 8B 0D 75 20 00 00 mov         rcx,qword ptr [__imp_std::cout (07FF667BF3080h)]  
00007FF667BF100B BA 01 00 00 00       mov         edx,1  
00007FF667BF1010 FF 15 72 20 00 00    call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (07FF667BF3088h)]  
00007FF667BF1016 48 8B C8             mov         rcx,rax  
00007FF667BF1019 E8 B2 00 00 00       call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (07FF667BF10D0h)  
    std::cout << test2 <<'\n';
00007FF667BF101E 48 8B 0D 5B 20 00 00 mov         rcx,qword ptr [__imp_std::cout (07FF667BF3080h)]  
00007FF667BF1025 BA 01 00 00 00       mov         edx,1  
00007FF667BF102A FF 15 58 20 00 00    call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (07FF667BF3088h)]  
00007FF667BF1030 48 8B C8             mov         rcx,rax  
00007FF667BF1033 E8 98 00 00 00       call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (07FF667BF10D0h)  


    return 0;
00007FF667BF1038 33 C0                xor         eax,eax  
}
00007FF667BF103A 48 83 C4 28          add         rsp,28h  
00007FF667BF103E C3                   ret
```

Comment: Never put `main()` (or compile into executable) when you want to test function-specific optimizations. It is going to inline aggressively, and shortcut all evaluations. If you must use `main()`, make sure to pass arguments of main to your check function, but better yet just not have it and compile into .o

Comment: @SergeyA Even if I pass the arguments it still optimizes the functions away. I understand to call from another compilation unit it will be forced to do without the full optimization. Either way I think this supports the argument that it is not worth a programmer's time to worry about this.

Comment: Where does OP say he calls the function with hard-coded values? If that were so, why would you need a function to do it, or the compiler to optimise the function away? Did you mean that the compiler effectively converts the function to `inline`?

Comment: @WeatherVane With hardcoded values it is not even inlined. It's optimized away completely.

Comment: What was the point of that then? OP says nothing about hardcoded values, possibly except for `myConst`. Are you answering a question that was not asked? Please input the values from a keyboard at runtime, not in the source code that a smart compiler can detect.

Comment: @WeatherVane True, this doesn't show the general case.